Type '{ onClose: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'onClose' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
first time asking here, can you help me to understand why my code trigger this error:
Type '{ onClose: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'onClose' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles/Navbar.css";
import Sidebar from "./SidebarComponent";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import { PropertyTypeComponent } from "./SidebarComponent";
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';

const ProfileMenu = () => {
  return (
    <div className="profile-menu">
      <a href="#" className="profile-menu-item">
        Account
      </a>
      <a href="#" className="profile-menu-item">
        Settings
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

const Search = () => {
  return (
    <div className="search-container">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
        <input type="search" name="search_bar" className="search-bar" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const Profile = () => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState<boolean | null>(false);
  return (
    <div className="profile-btn-container">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="profile-btn"
        id="profile-btn"
        onClick={() => {
          if (isClicked !== true) {
            setIsClicked(true);
          } else {
            setIsClicked(false);
          }
        }}
      >
        Profile
      </button>
      {isClicked && <ProfileMenu />}
    </div>
  );
};

const OpenDrawer = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => {setIsOpen(true)}}>
        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
      </button>
      <Drawer
        open={isOpen}
        anchor="right">
        **<PropertyTypeComponent onClose={() => {setIsOpen(false)}}/>**
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navbar-container">
      <div>
        <Search />
        <Profile />
        <OpenDrawer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

and here is the code for the "PropertyTypeComponent":
const PropertyTypeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="property-type-container">
      <a href="#">Apartments</a>
      <a href="#">Villa, Cottages</a>
      <a href="#">Townhouses</a>
      <a href="#">Residential Complex</a>
      <a href="#">Retail</a>
    </div>
  );
};

What I am trying to do is to pass the onclose prop to a component named "PropertyTypeComponent".

const PropertyTypeComponent = () => {

You havn't specified what props this component takes, so typescript assumes it doesn't take any props. Thus, it is an error to try to pass an onClose prop in to it.
To add support for an onClose prop, there are a couple ways you could do the type definition:
interface Props {
  onClose: () => void;
}
const PropertyTypeComponent = (props: Props) => {
  // ...
}

Or:
import { FC } from 'react';

interface Props {
  onClose: () => void;
}
const PropertyTypeComponent: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  // ...
}

(FC is short for "function component")

PS: There's a chance that you didn't mean to pass this into PropertyTypeComponent at all, but rather meant to pass it into Drawer. If so, ignore the type changes i suggested, and instead move the prop.
<Drawer
  open={isOpen}
  anchor="right"
  onClose={() => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }}
>
  <PropertyTypeComponent />
</Drawer>

